# Numpy: assign different values to different rows using mask

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Say I have an array `p` in shape `(m, n)`, an thresholds vector `Ts` in shape `(m)`. I want to replace value in `p` using the following rule:

```py
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):
        if p[i, j] > Ts[i]:
            p[i, j] = Ts[i]
```

My implementation is:

```
newP = np.zeros_like(p)
cond = p > Ts[:, None]
newP += cond * Ts[:, None]
newP += ~cond * p
p = newP
```

It definitely looks ugly. I want to know if there's any way like `p[cond]=Ts` style. Thanks :)

---

An example:

```
# m = 2, n = 5
p = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
              [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]])
Ts = np.array([3, 8])
expected_new_p = \
    np.array([[1, 2, 3, 3, 3],
              [6, 7, 8, 8, 8]])
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducable input

Comment: @[Akshay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4755954/akshay-sehgal) added.

Comment: So m,n is 10,5?

Comment: thanks for the examples, you can solve this simply by using `np.where` with broadcasted arrays as my answer suggests.

Comment: @markdana Have a look at my answer using `np.minimum()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most readable solution would be to use `np.minimum()` to extract element-wise minimums between `p` and the broadcasted array `Ts[:,None]`:

```
p = np.minimum(p, Ts[:,None])
```

Comment: Thanks. Great solution! And what if there're two Thresholds `Ts_max` and `Ts_min`, and I want to set p into this limit? Except for `p = np.minimum(p, Ts_max[:, None]); p = np.maximum(p, Ts_min[:, None])`, is there any one-line expression?

Comment: btw, using `np.minimum()` is faster about ~10% than index and masking, in my test samples (n, m ~ 100).

Comment: answering my above comment: [np.clip](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html)

Comment: Ah, `np.clip()` seems perfect !

Comment: oops. in my random tests, `np.clip` is not as fast as it claims. it's even slower than `np.minimum(np.maximum)`. strange lol

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `np.where`. If condition is not met, then return element from broadcasted `Ts`, else return the respective `p` value.

```
np.where(p < Ts[:, None], p, Ts[:, None])
```

```
array([[1, 2, 3, 3, 3],
       [6, 7, 8, 8, 8]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compare `p` and `Ts` by adding an extra dimension to `Ts`, extract the locations where `p < Ts` with [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html). Then, ovewrite with the values from `Ts`:

```
i = np.where(p > Ts[:, None])
p[i] = Ts[i[0]]
```

Above, `i` is a tuple of arrays containing the indices in each dimensions of `p`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use np.tile to cast threshold array to input array. So you can use boolean indexing directly. This might be useful for you:

```
    m, n = 3, 4
    x = np.random.random((m,n))
    t = np.random.random((m))
    
    mask = x > t[:,np.newaxis]
    
    x[mask] = np.tile(t[:,np.newaxis], (1,n))[mask] #assigning values of t for True values to corresponding elements
```